# SQL Server In-line table function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble creating an in-line table function (a function which returns a table).

The function is very simple - it takes 'first name'(first letter) + 'last name' + birth date:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_username
RETURNS TABLE   
AS
    RETURN 
        (SELECT
             LEFT(FirstName, 1) + LastName +
             CAST(YEAR(BirthDate) AS varchar(20)) 
         FROM Employees)
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_username, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 26]
> Incorrect syntax near 'RETURNS'.
>
> Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_username, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 26]
> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Can anyone please tell me what is its problem? I already build similar functions and didn't have any problem .

Thank you all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems.

1. You don't define your parameters. If your function has no parameters, you still must define that with `()` after the function's name.
2. You are over using parenthesis (`()`). You wrap the entire query in these, making it a subquery and implying you want to return a scalar value, not a table.
3. You omit an alias for your column.

Fix these, and you end up with the following:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_username()
RETURNS table   
AS RETURN
    SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(FirstName,1),LastName,YEAR(BirthDate)) AS YourColumnAlias
    FROM dbo.Employees;
```

Note I also switch to `CONCAT` as it's more concise, though if you want `NULL` if any of the columns are `NULL` you'll need to switch back to the concatenation operator (`+`).